# Python (pandas) : Remove duplicates row based on multiple columns But need to add the other columns of the duplicate entries

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe which contains duplicates values according to two columns (A and B):

```
A B C
1 2 1
1 2 4
2 7 1
3 4 2
3 4 8
```

I want to remove the duplicates by keeping the columns A and B and C should be the sum of the duplicate entries

```
A B C
1 2 5
2 7 1
3 4 10
```

I cannot figure out how to implement this in my code!! Please help

Comment: Use `df = df.groupby(['A','B'], as_index=False)['C'].sum()`

Comment: df=df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum()['C']